# How to prove that if det$A= 0$, then $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove that if det$ A = 0$, then $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions?

$A$ is square matrix.

I have no idea how to approach this problem.
HELP!

Comment: Should it say "$Ax=b$ either has $0$ or infinitely many solutions"?

Comment: If $Ax=b$ and $Av=0$, then any scalar $\lambda$ satisfies $A(x+\lambda v)=b$, and there are infinitely many vectors of the form $x+\lambda v$. Can you see why $Av=0$ has a solution, i.e. why $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: Oh, I understand! Thank you for clear reply

Comment: Or it should read: "There is not exactly one solution."

Comment: It should be also clarified over what field you are working.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Consider the $1 \times 1$-matrix $A= (0)$.

Then $Ax=(1)$ has no solutions.

Comment: Right. Actually this system has either no solution or infinitely many solution